# Media Query working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: css, media-queries

I have written a media query for chrome which is not working properly in Firefox.

I'm trying for a `1366*768` screen resolution.

I have attached both a working screenshot of Chrome and not a working screenshot of Firefox.

HTML:

```
    <div class="row m-row--no-padding m-row--col-separator-xl">
        <div class="my-widget-gridster">
          <!-- Widget Gridster-->
          <gridster *ngIf="data.length>0" [options]="options">
            <gridster-item [item]="item" [ngClass]="{ 'gridster-item-maximize': item.pod.podMaximized }" *ngFor="let item of data; let i= index;" (contextmenu)="onPodContextMenu($event, item); $event.preventDefault()" >
              <e-pod [type]="type" [refreshCount]="count"  [iPodModel]="item.pod"  [index]="i"  (widgetMinMaxEmit)="onPodMaximize($event, item, i)"></e-pod>
            </gridster-item>
          </gridster>
        </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {
    .gridster-item-maximize {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        display: block;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
        width: 74.6% !important;
        height: 78.8% !important;
        top: 20.6%;
        left: 24.9%;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

Expected: media query written for Chrome should work for all the browsers.

Actual: working for chrome, not in Firefox.

## Chrome:

[image: Working chrome screenshot]

## Firefox:

[image: Not working in firefox screenshot]

Comment: Post your HTML also

Comment: Different browsers use different render engines. You need prefixes for different browsers `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` would be `-moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` for firefox and `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` for safari and `-o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` for opera.

Comment: @RohithBalaji this was more of a problem a couple of years ago, nowadays you don't need many prefixes anymore. Opera uses the same rendering engine as Chrome so you don't need different prefixes for Opera. Also this question is about mediaqueries and not CSS prefixes.

Comment: I am guessing this is caused by one of firefox's default (user agent's) stylesheet. Try adding `!important` to all your css properties then eliminate them one by one? Most likely it's your `left` property.

Comment: is u add the Responsive Meta Tag?

Comment: I have tried all the cases which you people have mentioned above but still facing same issue.